# android too long text for scrollable view

Tags: java, android

Here is the code;

```xml
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bghome" >

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Wrocław"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20dp" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextMain"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="400dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
                android:text="Ładowanie danych..." >
            </TextView>
        </ScrollView>
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Now. When I put quite long text in the TextView (inside scrollable view). I get distortion problem. Top of the text gets cut down. (Goal is to create a title and below it a scrollable container for html text from serwer - a html code).

Id doesn't matter is I put html string on plain string, or I get data from serwer or hardcode it. I tried every combination, and I can't crack it.

```
MainText.setText(Html.fromHtml(Plain_str));
MainText.setText(Plain_str);
MainText.setText(Plain_str.toString());
```

Nothing helps.

Comment: Just out of interest, is this your entire XML file?

Comment: What happens if you set the `TableRow` height to 400dp and then `match_parent` for the `ScrollView` and `TextView`. I had issues with this layout heights until I made that change and then it *seems* everything works fine.

Comment: Hey guys, thanx for your answears. I found out the problem. It was in this line: android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right". (I don't understand why). Explanation welcome :)

Comment: "Normal" gravity is ok. Layout gravity is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in this line: android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding the question, but have you tried setting the `TableRow` height to `400dp` and then `match_parent` for the `ScrollView` and `TextView`? I had issues with this layout heights until I made that change and then it seems everything works fine.

Something like this:

```xml
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextMain"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
            android:text="this is very long text that is going in a textview wrapped by a scrollview. I want to see how the text is displayed when wrapped. this is very long text that is going in a textview wrapped by a scrollview. I want to see how the text is displayed when wrapped." >
        </TextView>
    </ScrollView>

</TableRow>
```

Comment: Thx. But I meant text like 100 times longer then this one :). Anyway gravity was the problem.

Comment: Good catch, although I'm not sure why that would have created an issue. Did you want the `TextView` to be `center_vertical | right` or the Text within the view? Since this is the only child and it fits parent assigning it to the `TextView` seems redundant, unless I am missing something, try replacing it with `android:gravity="center_vertical|right"` if you want to assign those to the text within the view.

Comment: I was experimenting with creating of text justify in the android.